# Cannot determine size of graphic in Overleaf

Tags: graphics, overleaf

Overleaf uses `pdflatex` but I still get this error when I try to insert a `.png` image.
`\includegraphics{screenshots/AB4results.png}`

> In fact, Overleaf has a `.png` file in its template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}
The universe is immense and it seems to be homogeneous, 
in a large scale, everywhere we look at.

\includegraphics{universe}

There's a picture of a galaxy above
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Here are all the packages I'm using.

```
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

%matlab
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

%\usepackage{pdfpages}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}

\usepackage{natbib}

%inserting png images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\usepackage{extarrows}
```

Edit: I included the size in the code and the error disappeared:
`\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,natwidth=489,natheight=436]{screenshots/AB4results.png}`

However, the image still does not appear.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ Could you click on the Overleaf menu icon above the file tree panel, and check that the project's Compiler option is indeed set to "pdflatex", not "LaTeX"?

Comment: And if you are indeed using `pdflatex`, then you should remove `natwidth=489,natheight=436`.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Many thanks.